# awkward DLL exports section

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, dllexport, dumpbin

I have a section of C++ code in MSVC2010 that creates a DLL wrapper.  The section of code looks something like this...

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) DWORD myDllExportFunction()
{
    return (DWORD)SomeFunction(SomeParameter);
}
```

or...

```
_declspec(dllexport) int64 _stdcall myDllExportFunction2(<someType> someParameter){
{
    return new (DWORD)SomeExternalFunction(SomeParameter);
}
```

I would expect my exports section from doing a dumpbin on this dll to contain just the fully qualified function name however it looks more like this.

```
 _myDllExportFunction@12 = _myDllExportFunction@12
```

I have no idea why this equal sign is there or what it means.  I have a strong feeling that the function is not accessible by programs which import the dll as it is not doing what it is supposed to.

for sake of providing enough information I have included some of my compiler and linker switches

Compiler Options:

```
/Zi /nologo /Wall /WX- /O2 /Ob2 /Oi /Oy- /D "_WINDLL" /D "_MBCS" /D "_AFXDLL" /Gm- /EHsc /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc
```

Linker Options:

```
/MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG /PDB:"C:\....\MyProj.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF /PGD:"C:\....\MyProj.pgd" /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE:NO /NXCOMPAT:NO /IMPLIB:"MyProj.lib" /MACHINE:X86 /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE
```

Note:  /IMPLIB:"MyProj.lib"  ->  This import library has all of the exports that I want to have in my DLL in the format that I want them to be in the dll.

Is there any setting in my projects options that would cause this?  Was there any changes to dllexport in the past years that I might have missed?  Is there any information that I could provide you that would help you understand my problem?

Comment: Delete the .pdb file to get less confuzzling output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try turning off debug information generation.

[image]

Comment: This does NOT affect the names of exported functions.

Comment: @BenVoigt This was actually the error that I was describing in the problem.  +1, but not enough rep to :*(

Answer (score 0):

You have mangled the name by declaring it `__stdcall`, presumably in a separate declaration. You must give it the `__cdecl` calling convention to avoid name mangling.

Comment: `__cdecl` doesn't avoid name mangling, it just changes the rules.

Comment: @BenVoigt This actually appeared to remove the mangling when I tried this, however I did not ask to remove the mangling (I still wanted to see).

Comment: @Ben:  It can effect name mangling: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7kb4e2f.aspx

Comment: I mean, im looking right at a project that I've been building minute after minute, and it does for me.  I think that's proof enough.  It seems that it only removes name mangling if it is defined `extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) <Type> __cdecl functionName(functionParams)` not possitive but I think `extern "C"` combined with this is what is removing the mangling.

Comment: It changes the mangling rules.  With `extern "C" __cdecl`, the only mangling is adding a leading underscore.  On x86, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control the names of exported functions (for example, to remove mangling), you'll need to use a linker [module definition (`.def`) file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms923590.aspx).

Comment: I dont need to remove name mangling, however I have tried this and I get linker errors which makes me thing that it is not finding these methods in my C classes.  Here is an example of the def file...  [code]LIBRARY myProjectname
EXPORTS
"myDllExportFunction@12"[/code]

Comment: @Satyrn: Just put the function name into the .def file, like `LIBRARY myProjectname EXPORTS myDllExportFunction`.  No quotes, no stack size annotation.  You might possibly need `EXPORTS myDllExportFunction = _myDllExportFunction@12`, but usually the linker figures that out.  Do pay attention to leading underscores.

Comment: I found the solution in another persons answer, however just simply trying to use a def file gives me LNK2001 errors "unresolved external symbol" and I dont particularly know why.  I removed the name mangling in the def files for each of my functions.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different options to prevent name mangling.

- Change the declaration specifier for the exported function from
  `__stdcall` to `__cdecl`. So the function signature should look like
  this

  `extern "C" DWORD __declspec(dllexport) __cdecl myDllExportFunction()`

If you must use the `__stdcall` calling convention use one of the following two methods to get around name mangling. In both cases you do not need to add `__declspec(dllexport)` to the function definition (but it's OK if you do).

- Add a .def file to the project containing the lines

> LIBRARY   YourLibraryName 
>       EXPORTS
>           myDllExportFunction

- In the project properties, go to *Linker -> Command Line* and in the edit box for *Additional Options* add `/export:myDllExportFunction`

Comment: I think the list of exported functions goes under the `EXPORTS` keyword, not on the same line.  And `__cdecl` function names will still be mangled with a leading underscore.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks, you're right about the def file syntax. But `__cdecl` function names are not mangled with a leading underscore, I've got a working project open in front of me that proves otherwise.

Comment: x86 or x64.  That changes the rules too.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#C_name_decoration_in_Microsoft_Windows

Comment: @BenVoigt It's an x86 C project compiled with VS2005. No mangling happens unless I change the calling convention to `__stdcall`; I don't know why Wikipedia is saying what it is.

Comment: @BenVoigt Dependency walker, I have the option "Undecorate C++ Functions" unchecked, but I suppose it might be stripping the leading underscore

Comment: Ok, it looks like the actual symbol in the .obj file has a leading underscore, but the DLL export table doesn't (checked with Dependency Walker, `dumpbin`, and the VS binary editor).  I think this has changed though, with different versions of Visual C++.  In contrast, for `__stdcall`, the exported name is identical to the symbol name.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks for digging into that, you had me puzzled for a while